# Find current and historic (15 years) delistings in the US stock market

Tags: equities, historical-data, edgar, data-source, ticker-mapping

I wonder if there is any source for the following information concerning stock delistings in the US stock market:

- date and stock symbol of the delisting (required)
- covers at least 15 years history (required)
- should be a trustworthy source (required)
- reasons for delisting (optional)
- best as structured data like a CSV, export of some sort or API (optional, but preferred)

It doesn't need to be free, I am willing to pay for the data.

I know that there are similar questions, this is what I have found and tried but didn't work:

- CSRP database seems to have this data, but CSRP is not accessible to me
- https://listingcenter.nasdaq.com/IssuersPendingSuspensionDelisting.aspx this only shows current data, but no history
- Searching directly for Form 25 in SEC/Edgar also only lists the most recent data

  - https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?company=&CIK=&type=25-NSE&owner=include&count=40&action=getcurrent

Is there any other source I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Norgate Data provides paid subscription access to delisted stock data back to 1950 (Diamond package) or 1990 (Platinum package), offers a Python API and export of price data to ASCII.

Disclosure: I am a co-owner of Norgate Data.

Answer (score 1):

Try Algoseek - for each trading day, they provide an as-is dataset from that trade date with every Stock, ETFs, ETNs, Warrants, Preferred Stocks, ADRs, and even test symbols from January 2007 to Present. Meaning, data includes all listed and “dead” symbols due to bankruptcy, M&A, or any other reasons.

You can also score some free historical data from their newly launched website's virtual data drive. Gives you the ability to explore the data set from your browser/export csv files to your local computer.

Comment: Thanks. It is polite to mention if you have a relationship with a company (or not).

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same exact thing at the moment. Currently I am using an API from FinancialModelingPrep which is pretty thorough and concise, about $20 / mo. (great customer service too!) but I haven't seen anything for delisting data.

Edit: Bingo!! https://site.financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs#Delisted-Companies

Btw I don't work for them, I've just had a good experience with them so far.